# How do I stop similar values in the same dimension from being combined in Tableau?

Tags: mysql, tableau-api

I imported a table of MySQL data into Tableau. When I put the single dimension I have in as a row I noticed that it will combine values if they're spelled the same even though the case sensitivity is different.

For example my MySQL table might look like this...

```
+---------+---------+---------+---------+
| Value A | Value B | Value C | Value D |
+---------+---------+---------+---------+
| Google  | 2       | 1       | 240.75  |
+---------+---------+---------+---------+
| google  | 498     | 111     | 140.25  |
+---------+---------+---------+---------+
```

But then when I put it into Tableau it looks like this...

```
+---------+---------+---------+---------+
| Value A | Value B | Value C | Value D |
+---------+---------+---------+---------+
| google  | 500     | 112     | 381     |
+---------+---------+---------+---------+
```

How do I keep the values separated even though they're spelled the same?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

There's a setting to prevent the aggregating of your measures - Analysis menu - uncheck Aggregate Measures.

If your question is more around the merging of the word "google" it seems more tricky. You can force separate these using INDEX() - i.e. create a field with the formula and put it as a discrete value in front of [Value A].

There may be a better way I can't think of, I am interested to hear the suggestions of others.